# Pyqt5 QDialog widget should not open when included QTableview doesn't have data

Tags: pyqt5

I have a QDialog widget that among other includes a QPushbutton to close de form and a QtableView showing the data form a QSqlQuery for further processing. The idea is to interrupt or close the form opening when there is not data available (qry.size() < 1). I place a closeWidget method that's fired both by the QPushbotton and or called when the "no data condition" occurs that should close the form.

When calling the closing method from the QPushBotton the form closes as expected, but when it is called by the "no data condition" both from the `__init__` or from inside the setUI methods the form continues does not interrupt opening.

I tried the following: Placing the ""o data condition" inside the setUI method; place the "no data contrition" at the end of the setUI method, and placing the no data condition inside the `__init__` method after calling the setUI method without succeeding.

As far as the closing code I intended self.close(), super().close(), and self.done(QDialog.rejected) with similar results.

I'am also calling the closing methods from inside a refresh table method when the condition applies in which case it works just fine.

I suppose that I am entering inside a loop. Any help would be most appreciated

Note: The QTableView is a custom class derived from it (TableViewAndModel) but I guess it's not affecting the results since the condition is fired properly by the query.

```
    def __init__(self, mode, db, con_string, agreementId=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.agreementId = agreementId
        self.con_string = con_string
        self.db = db
        if not self.db.isOpen():
            self.db.open()
        self.parent = parent
        self.supplierId = parent.supplierId
        # ...
        self.mode = mode
        if not self.db.isOpen():
            self.db.open()
        self.setModal(True)
        self.setUI()

    def setUI(self):
        # ...
        self.pushCancel = QPushButton('Close')
        self.pushCancel.setMaximumWidth(80)
        self.pushCancel.clicked.connect(self.closeWidget)
        colorDict = {}
        if self.mode == OPEN_NEW:

            colDict = {0 :("Provider", True, True, False, None ),
                       1 :("AgrID", False, True, True, None),
                       # ...
                       }
        else:

            colDict = {0 :("Provider", True, True, False, None ),
                       # ...
                       }
        qryLoad = QSqlQuery(self.db)
        qryLoad.exec("CALL receivebroken_loadhorses({}, '{}', {})".format(self.agreementId,
                 self.dateDor.date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                 self.mode))
        if qryLoad.lastError().type() != 0:
            raise DataError("setUI - load horse", qryLoad.lastError().text())
        self.table = TableViewAndModel(colDict, colorDict, (100,100), qryLoad)
        self.table.doubleClicked.connect(self.getHorseData)

        # ...

        vLayout.addLayout(hLayout)
        self.setLayout(vLayout)
        if qryLoad.size() < 1:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "No data", "There are not horses to be considered!", 
                               QMessageBox.Ok)
            self.closeWidget()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def closeWidget(self):
        super().close()
        #self.done(QDialog.Rejected)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I've completely understood your code, but I'm afraid that you're trying to close the widget before it's actually shown. If you're executing/showing the dialog *after* creating it (as soon as you create the instance), `closeWidget()` has already been called at that point. That said, you shouldn't create the dialog and check if any data exists, but you should check if the data exists in the first place and *then* create the dialog if necessary.

Comment: I solved the issue by raising an error when the "no data condition" happens on opening. Thank you musicmante!

Comment: Ok, but I suggest you to keep in mind what I wrote before: if there's no data, the dialog shouldn't be created at all (there's no use to create it if has to be immediately closed: just show a message box to notify the user). Also, please take some time to read how to better [format your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), avoid unnecessary characters that might just distract the reading, and be careful about [paragraph formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), since a big single condensed block of text is not easy to read.

Comment: Ok, I took musicamante suggestion and works just fine, and seems to be the cleaner solution to this issue